# Find Duplicate value with multiple fields then sum the specific field sql query

Tags: sql

I have the same problem with this i want to get those duplicate values and i successfully done it using this code

```
SELECT projNum, ProjCode, LaborCode, Code, Description, Price, QtyMaterials, AIPrice
FROM Cost_MasterMaterials
WHERE Code IN (
    SELECT Code
    FROM Cost_MasterMaterials
    GROUP BY Code
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

but my problem is after i get the details of the duplicate values and all its field i want to sum the QTYMaterials then retain only one item of every duplicate values.

Sample Table

```
id | projnum | projcode | code | description | Price | QtyMaterials | AIPrice, 
1      23        Null     1207    Dog           Null       1          Null
2      23        Null     1207    Dog           Null       2          Null
3       2        Null     1321    Pig           Null       5          Null
4      12        Null     1621    Cat           Null       6           Null
5       2        Null     1321    Pig           Null       1          Null
```

Result must be like this

```
id | projnum | projcode | code | description | Price | QtyMaterials | AIPrice, 
1      23        Null     1207    Dog           Null       3          Null
3       2        Null     1321    Pig           Null       6          Null
4      12        Null     1621    Cat           Null       6          Null
```

I Hope someone can help me of this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM` with `GROUP BY`

Try this

```sql
SELECT 
    projNum, ProjCode, LaborCode, Code, Description, 
    Price, SUM(QtyMaterials) QtyMaterials, AIPrice
FROM Cost_MasterMaterials
GROUP BY projNum, ProjCode, LaborCode, Code, Description, Price, AIPrice
```

Comment: good answer includes an explanation as well as working code. Thanks u..

Comment: thanks for this it really solved my problem

Comment: @MelDelMusicWhisperYou could give upvote and accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is basically you need aggregated value of the Materials or any aggregation field of you choice.

In your case you want to see what are the duplicate records by at code level basically. So you can do  this by looking at your data, one is include all the fields in group by clause - given that all the other values associated are same, you end up having only 1 record ( which will also delete the duplicate at your level) or you can do the MIN/MAX operation on the string fields as well to uniquely get the records at the CODE level (Provided you have only 1-1 mapping of Code to rest of the attributes).

1. Option 1 is already highlighted by Nayanish Damania. Use the script
2. Option 2

SELECT MIN(ID) as ID, MIN(PROJNUM) as PROJNUM, ProjCode ,MIN(description) as description , mIN(Price) as PRICE , MIN(Price) as PRICE, SUM(QtyMaterials) as QtyMaterials
FROM Cost_MasterMaterials
GROUP BY ProjCode
ORDER BY MIN(ID) ASC;